# Should I lay artificial grass over pavers or sand?

Tags: outdoor, landscaping, grass, paving, garden

We have limestone paving slabs throughout our entire garden but I'm hoping to do some artificial grass now in an area to break it up a bit. The slabs are 22mm thick.

My question is, shall I just lay the artificial grass on the slabs directly or lift them and lay the grass on the sand mix under the slabs?

I'm just conscious of it all feeling as level and flush with each other as possible as we have 3 young kids.

If I'm going with laying on top of slabs I assume a thinner pile grass and if I'm lifting up the slabs to lay the grass is a 40mm pile too much?

And depending on which I go for I'm assuming an artificial grass glue/bonding agent on the slabs and then bonding/joining tape and staples if applying on the sand mix, would that be right?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't that a question for the manufacturer? What kind of backing does the product have? What does its literature say?